# Installing Microsoft Enterprise Libraries and DatabaseFactory

Tags: enterprise-library

I'm attempting to use the DatabaseFactory method from the Microsoft Enterprise Library.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
```

The error I get is: `The type or namespace 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft`

I tried going to Microsoft's site to install the Enterprise Library, worked through the installation process and it still doesn't work. Did I install it to the wrong location? Any ideas?

Edit: I followed Kev's directions and got everything working. Thanks for your guys' help.

Comment: Which version are you using? Go to http://entlib.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add references in your project to:

> `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll`
>   `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll`

Assuming you installed `Enterprise Library 4.1 - October 2008`, the default install location will be:

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1 - October 2008\`

You can locate the assemblies you need to reference in:

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1 - October 2008\Bin`

These assemblies are also listed in the Add References (.NET) dialogue:

> `Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block`
>   `Enterprise Library Shared Library`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the reference to your project. Follow the instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511706.aspx

From that article, you also need a few other references:

- Add a reference to the Data Access Application Block assembly. In Visual Studio, right-click your project node in Solution Explorer, and then click Add References. Click the Browse tab, and then navigate to the location of the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll assembly. Select the assembly, and then click OK to add the reference.
- Following the same procedure, add references to the Enterprise Library Core assemblies, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll and Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll.*

Let us know how you made out.